# How_To_Solve_ReactJS_Problem

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Sorry for my bad english and a new learner programming.

I have a single problem with React.JS in App.js,

I have written an exterrnal JS file, called Fundamental.js, the code is the following:

```
const testing = () => {
    console.log('test log 12456');
}
export default testing;
```

When I import Fundamental.js file into App.js, my VS Code shows a popup message:

> 'testing' is defined but never used.

how to solve it?

the import list in my React App.js is:

```
import logo from './Linux_Logo.png';
import './App.css';
import testing from './FundaMental';
```

Thank you so much to whoever solves my problem!

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SOF. In your component testing should be Testing [capitalized] and In testing nothing is returned that's why showing this in the terminal. Try this plz:

```
import React from 'react';

  function Testing() {
    return (
       console.log('test log 12456');   
  )
}
export default Testing
```

when importing:

```
import Testing from './FundaMental';
```

It is better to keep the same name of the function name and the js file name.

Answer (score 0):

VS Code is saying that you imported a function but you're not using it.

Your `testing` module *defines* the function `testing`. It doesn't *execute* it.

There are two ways to get rid of the warning:

1. Call the `testing` function in `App.js`, or
2. Don't import it into `App.js`.

If `testing` is the beginning of a React component then follow @Pabel Mahbub's answer, including the suggestion to rename the function `Testing` and rename the file `Testing.js`. As your app grows that will make it easier to manage.

Answer (score 0):

This is only a warning/reminder that you import something but you never used it. React has this kind of checking that will warn us of the unusual code that we have. To fix this warning either trigger the function or remove it. Hope this helps!